# remove semicolon from end of string

Tags: python

I want to remove semicolon from the end of a string in python:

```
mystring = 'NM_000106.5:c.985+39G>A;c.886C>T;c.1457G>C;'
```

I tried something like this:

```
clean_end = mystring[:-1] if mystring.endswith(';') else mystring
```

However in this case, `mystring.endswith(';')` returns `False`.

Why is this?

Comment: `python` `strings` has `rstrip` method. It means right strip. It strips values if there. TL;DR: `mystring.rstrip(';')` should work.

Comment: The semi-colon at the end of 'mystring' is the character U+037e. The one in your condition 'mystring.endswith(...)' is the character U+003b. This is why your condition is evaluated as 'False'.

Comment: [`removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) looks like what you want. (version >= 3.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using a regular `;`, but a **greek question mark** (`;`).

| Name | Char | Hex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| greek question mark | `;` | `0x37e` |
| semicolon | `;` | `0x3b` |

---

So change the `endswith` param to the correct one:

```
mystring.endswith(';')
```

Comment: oh my goodness!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same character, they just look similar

```py
>>> 'NM_000106.5:c.985+39G>A;c.886C>T;c.1457G>C;'.endswith(';')  # Your code
False
>>> 'NM_000106.5:c.985+39G>A;c.886C>T;c.1457G>C;'.endswith(';')  # Character copied and pasted from the end of the string
True
```